# getting status of mailboxes in gmail not working

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

Hi i am implementing client email application. My Requirement is i need to check the status of all the available mailboxes. so, When i am connecting yahoo mail server and tried  following command working

```
A STATUS * (MESSAGES HIGHESTMODSEQ)
```

Response

```
A STATUS * (MESSAGES HIGHESTMODSEQ)  
* STATUS "Bulk Mail" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5984401168814718896 MESSAGES 0)
* STATUS "Child 1" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5984638672136689104 MESSAGES 0)
* STATUS "Draft" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5983840366982492584 MESSAGES 0)
* STATUS "Inbox" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5984607584865222656 MESSAGES 5)
* STATUS "Sent" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5984326836620652024 MESSAGES 12)
* STATUS "Trash" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 5984638530536302336 MESSAGES 1)
```

When i am connecting to gmail the same command returning with following error

```
A BAD Could not parse command
```

What is missing there in gmail. Is there alternate solution to solve for gmail ? Pls help me out...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at RFC 3501¸ page 44, the first line about STATUS:

```
   Arguments:  mailbox name
```

`*` is not a valid mailbox name. Yahoo has some nonstandard extension and accepts a glob pattern.

Comment: ya i already checked that arnt. i know that, but yahoo accepting na thatswhy i thought i am missing something to get all the box status for gmail....